# Web scraping Stock Challenge: Nonetype object has no attribute start

Tags: python

Beginner in Python and new to CS.

For the challenge question of array.

[group with array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VLgU.png)

Tried group but can't even get value running with userinput.
[group with userinput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6zXn.png)

As for start, end, run smoothly for all the company names in the array with userinput.

However,

```
import re
import urllib.request
url = "#this is counted as link but I don't have more than 10 reputation."

arrayofStocks = ["FB", "GOOG", "DATA", "BABA"]

for i in range(0, 4):
    url = url + arrayofStocks[i]

    data= urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

    data1=data.decode("utf-8")



m=re.search('meta itemprop="price"',data1)
start=m.start()
end=start+50
newString = data1[start:end]


m=re.search("content=",newString)
start=m.end()
newString1=newString[start:]
m=re.search("/",newString1)
start =0
end=m.end()-3
final=newString1[0:end]
print("The value of " +arrayofStocks[i].upper()+" is "+final)
```

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
>   /Users/ying2ra/PycharmProjects/stock/Final The value of FB is "127.21
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/ying2ra/PycharmProjects/stock/Final", line 17, in 
>       start=m.start() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What happened to my var `m` after the first run since FB has its own value?

APIs are good solution but google closed their API for google finance.

Comment: have you done any simple debugging: adding some print statements to see if m has a value (and what value) before you run the .start method?  did you print the data or data1 to see what is in there, or if it returning anything?  Since you are new, you should check out [PDB](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) the python debugger.  If you will be continuing with programming, knowing it will be helpful going forward.

Comment: Your regex finds nothing and you should be using a HTML parser .

Comment: pre_url = "#this is counted as link but I don't have more than 10 reputation.url = pre_url + arrayofStocks[i]" will solve the problem.Thanks ivan7707 for PDB and the "print" idea. Also thanks Padraic for HTML parser though have no idea how.